# How can I improve the performance of my Boot2Docker vm

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I have been running our SoA on docker on my mac.

It has seven containers:

- three rails apps
- rabbit
- postgres
- elasticsearch
- a data volume for rubygems

It runs so slowly compared with my mac. (gulp for example takes 1 hour to read all the files in the manifies on docker but only 10s on the mac).

I increased the memory to 8GB for the VM but it only uses about 2GB so that is not the issue.

Has anyone any ideas (I know this is vague). Perhaps there is some VM tuning I can do. I have a suspicion that this has to do with file io but I am not knowledgable enough to know how to validate that not to mind tune the VM enough to resolve it.

Note: the rails apps are mounted from a volume from the host mac. And similarly postgres, rabbit, and elasticseach store there data on a volume mounted from the mac also.

Comment: Are the manifest files mounted in using volumes or part of the docker image? The default union file system might be slowing down the system if there is a lot of file I/O

Comment: They are mounted - I think that is indeed the issue.

Comment: So on boot2docker the mounts happen using an sshfs file system. This may be slowing them down. On a linux machine volume mounting is much faster. If you could test this on a linux machine without boot2docker you should see an improvement.

Comment: Thanks Usman - I am going to try to use the vagrant provisioned docker and see how much of an improvement there is.

Comment: Boot2docker just runs a virtual box VM you could just do boot2docker ssh and run docker from there directly. If you find that easier then vagrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance of the mounted host folders is not very good with boot2docker on mac. Can be an issue with disk-intensive processes. A workaround I employ is to use [vagrant provisioned docker](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html), map host files there and run docker tasks from within vagrant. Bit cumbersome, but not too bad and performance is way better.

Comment: Thanks Mykola. I think I am going to try this out and see if I get better mileage.